# finding a Latin quote

Tags: medieval-latin, passage-request

I am reading the book "6/5" by Alexandre Laumonier, in French about high-frequency trading in electronic financial markets (bear with me). Near the end of "5", he says

> Pour autant, comme l'écrivit Juan de Lugo dans son *Disputationes de iustitia e iure* de 1642, "il ne me semble pas que l'on puisse nier que soit connu de Dieu un certain prix qui soit plus égal et juste que les autres. Notre incertitude quant au prix mathématique juste ne provient pas de la diversité des sentiments qui se portent sur les marchandises, mais de ce que nous ne savons pas de façon déterminée, en tenant compte de ce degré des sentiments variés, ou uniformes, à combien se monte la valeur mathématique juste de la chose". Juan de Lugo conclut: "*Pretium iustum mathematicum licet soli Deo notum*", seul Dieu peut connaître mathématiquement le prix d'une chose.

which in my rough translation is

> However, as Juan de Lugo wrote in his *Disputationes de iustitia e iure* of 1642, "it does not seem to me that one may deny that there is known to God a certain price which is more equal and fair than the others. Our uncertainty as to the true mathematical price does not come from the diversity of feelings which apply to the objects of trade, but from what we do not know in a deterministic way, taking account of the degree of these varied feelings, or uniform, as to what is the correct mathematical value of the object." Juan de Lugo finishes: "*Pretium iustum mathematicum licet soli Deo notum*", only God may know mathematically the price of a thing.

I would like to find this quote in the original, so I may understand more fully what Juan de Lugo is saying (and to impress my students). The book is available online and as a 95 Mb PDF download [here](https://books.google.ru/books?id=AUlFAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP5&focus=viewport&hl=ru) -- I believe this is the correct one although Juan de Lugo wrote several volumes of theology. But the PDF is 679 pages of poor quality scan, and my Latin is not good enough to skim it to find this quote. Can anyone advise me on how I might locate this quote? Or know where else I might look?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the site! You will be able to accept an answer and vote on content you like once you register your account. You seem to have created a new one, and [you can merge them to get full access to this question from your new account](https://latin.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). Let us know if you need help doing so!

Answer (score 6):

The first quote ("it does not seem to me...") can be seen [here](https://books.google.ru/books?id=AUlFAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP5&focus=viewport&hl=ru#v=onepage&q=mathematicum&f=false) (p. 312 of the book you linked to) -- it begins 10 lines from the bottom of the first column, "mihi non videtur posse negari...". The quote as given by Laumonier is compressed from Juan de Lugo's original -- the last phrase, "what is the correct mathematical value of the object", corresponds to lines 5-6 of the second column, "quantus sit valor iustus mathematicus rei".

I haven't found the exact phrase "Pretium iustum mathematicum licet soli Deo notum" -- maybe this too is a compression or paraphrase of the original.